# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-bot-service, azure-webapps

Looking to find a workaround for [this existing issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/713)

Using azure web app(linux) plan, linux_fx_version is `Python|3.7`

my requirement.txt is

```
botbuilder_schema==4.13.0
requests==2.25.0
aiohttp==3.7.4
botbuilder==0.0.1
botbuilder-core==4.13.0
botbuilder-dialogs==4.13.0
```

When I tried to do the zip deploy(`az webapp deployment source config-zip` ) the deployment goes well- with [Kudo zip deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip), except when starting my application it gives the error liks module not found `aiohttp`

Error log:

```
2021-06-28T07:35:59.154876250Z Build Operation ID: 58418482-e3f1-4f4f-8f3f-23c89fdc7228
2021-06-28T07:36:00.652990532Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20210420.1, Commit: 85c6e9278aae3980b86cb1d520aaad532c814ed7, ReleaseTagName: 20210420.1
2021-06-28T07:36:01.268742028Z Detected an app based on Flask
2021-06-28T07:36:01.270392332Z Generating `gunicorn` command for 'app:app'
2021-06-28T07:36:01.451069287Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2021-06-28T07:36:01.897311466Z WARNING: Could not find virtual environment directory /home/site/wwwroot/antenv.
2021-06-28T07:36:01.897342966Z WARNING: Could not find package directory /home/site/wwwroot/__oryx_packages__.
2021-06-28T07:36:02.714252775Z [2021-06-28 07:36:02 +0000] [35] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-06-28T07:36:02.715401977Z [2021-06-28 07:36:02 +0000] [35] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (35)
2021-06-28T07:36:02.715816178Z [2021-06-28 07:36:02 +0000] [35] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-06-28T07:36:02.725130896Z [2021-06-28 07:36:02 +0000] [38] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 38
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757363360Z [2021-06-28 07:36:02 +0000] [38] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757382760Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757439960Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757446560Z     worker.init_process()
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757450260Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757463360Z     self.load_wsgi()
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757467260Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757470560Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757473760Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757477360Z     self.callable = self.load()
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757480460Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757483660Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757486760Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757489960Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-06-28T07:36:02.757493160Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845882934Z     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845888734Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845892434Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845895934Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845899934Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845903534Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845906934Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845910134Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845913434Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845924834Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/app.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845929234Z     from aiohttp import web
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845932334Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'
2021-06-28T07:36:02.845936534Z [2021-06-28 07:36:02 +0000] [38] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 38)
2021-06-28T07:36:02.866740775Z [2021-06-28 07:36:02 +0000] [35] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-06-28T07:36:02.867504676Z [2021-06-28 07:36:02 +0000] [35] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I tried different version of `aiohttp` ,`request` and even increased `Python 3.8` nothing works so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there multiple things helps me to fix the issue.

1. By default Kudu assumes that zip deployments do not require any build-related actions like `npm install` or `dotnet publish`. So the cause in this case might be `pip installation` did not been taken care properly.

   To make it install all required packages in requirements.txt file automatically, we can simply set `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `true` in [appsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_deployment_source_config_zip), then deploy again.
2. Need to setup the startup command like

   ```
   gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --worker-class aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker --timeout 600 app:APP
   ```
3. Configure the `MicrosoftAppId` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` properly

[Reference](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/python/02.echo-bot/deploymentTemplates/template-with-preexisting-rg.json)

Comment: How do you set the startup command? Have you also set `pip install -r requirements.txt` as a startup command?

Comment: The startup command should be used on azure portal configuration level. and for your other question nope only i used the above startup command not the `pip install`

Answer (score 0):

It possibly can be that you are using `pip` instead of `pip3`.
Try to install your dependencies with `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`.

Another thing to notice out is, that if you are using a `virtual environment`, you need to install your dependencies in there, as well.

Comment: I never used `pip` or `pip3` for installing the dependencies manually, the  `az webapp deployment source config-zip` is doing all that behind the scene with the [kudo zip deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip)