# Teams Chatbot always throws [on_turn_error] unhandled error: 'access_token', even the samples form github

Tags: microsoft-teams, chatbot

so recently I started coding a chatbot with the Microsoft Bot Framework SDK.
But whatever I deploy to Azure ( even the samples (here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/57.teams-conversation-bot) throw a lot of access errors. The bot doesn't send a single message. And I really don't know how to fix them or why they appear (*edit* they appear whenever I message the bot).

More interestingly sometimes the bot even works, but only for a limited amount of time and messaging him like 100 times.
What am I doing wrong? Found nothing on the web that could really help me.

log stream:

```
2022-06-25T14:14:20.542164844Z Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
2022-06-25T14:14:33.947672347Z 11 added, 0 removed; done.
2022-06-25T14:14:33.948274356Z Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
2022-06-25T14:14:33.978379073Z done.
2022-06-25T14:14:34.028116464Z Updated CA certificates
2022-06-25T14:14:39.461850509Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Middleware[0]
2022-06-25T14:14:39.461884810Z       At least one of http20OnlyDestinationHostUrl and http20OnlyListenUrl not provided


Ending Log Tail of existing logs ---
Starting Live Log Stream ---
2022-06-25T14:27:43  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:28:43  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:29:43  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:30:43  No new trace in the past 4 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:31:43  No new trace in the past 5 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:32:43  No new trace in the past 6 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:33:43  No new trace in the past 7 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:34:43  No new trace in the past 8 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:35:43  No new trace in the past 9 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:36:43  No new trace in the past 10 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:37:43  No new trace in the past 11 min(s).
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642576589Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642618090Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/integration/aiohttp_channel_service_exception_middleware.py", line 20, in aiohttp_error_middleware
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642637490Z     response = await handler(request)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642642290Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py", line 927, in _handle
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642646990Z     raise self._http_exception
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642651090Z aiohttp.web_exceptions.HTTPNotFound: Not Found
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642655190Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642659290Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/integration/aiohttp_channel_service_exception_middleware.py", line 20, in aiohttp_error_middleware
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642663790Z     response = await handler(request)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642667790Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_urldispatcher.py", line 927, in _handle
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642672090Z     raise self._http_exception
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642676091Z aiohttp.web_exceptions.HTTPNotFound: Not Found
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642680291Z
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642684191Z  [on_turn_error] unhandled error: 'access_token'
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642688191Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642692191Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 128, in run_pipeline
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642696591Z     return await self._middleware.receive_activity_with_status(
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642700691Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642704991Z     return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642709091Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642713491Z     return await callback(context)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642717491Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/activity_handler.py", line 70, in on_turn
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642721791Z     await self.on_message_activity(turn_context)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642725791Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 61, in on_message_activity
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642730091Z     await self._send_card(turn_context, False)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642734091Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 121, in _send_card
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642738291Z     await self._send_welcome_card(turn_context, buttons)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642743091Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 135, in _send_welcome_card
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642747392Z     await turn_context.send_activity(
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642751292Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 174, in send_activity
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642759292Z     result = await self.send_activities([activity_or_text])
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642763492Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 226, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642767792Z     return await self._emit(self._on_send_activities, output, logic())
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642771892Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 304, in _emit
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642776192Z     return await logic
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642780092Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 221, in logic
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642784392Z     responses = await self.adapter.send_activities(self, output)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642788392Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 733, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642792792Z     raise error
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642796692Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 718, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642800992Z     response = await client.conversations.reply_to_activity(
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642805092Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/aio/operations_async/_conversations_operations_async.py", line 524, in reply_to_activity
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642809492Z     response = await self._client.async_send(
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642813492Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/async_client.py", line 115, in async_send
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642817692Z     pipeline_response = await self.config.pipeline.run(request, **kwargs)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642821793Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_abc.py", line 159, in run
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642825993Z     return await first_node.send(pipeline_request, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642830093Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_abc.py", line 79, in send
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642834293Z     response = await self.next.send(request, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642838393Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_requests.py", line 99, in send
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642842893Z     self._creds.signed_session(session)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642848693Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/auth/app_credentials.py", line 98, in signed_session
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642853093Z     auth_token = self.get_access_token()
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642857093Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/auth/microsoft_app_credentials.py", line 65, in get_access_token
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642861493Z     return auth_token["access_token"]
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642868993Z KeyError: 'access_token'
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642873193Z
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642877193Z  [on_turn_error] unhandled error: 'access_token'
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642881193Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642885193Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 128, in run_pipeline
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642889493Z     return await self._middleware.receive_activity_with_status(
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642893694Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642897994Z     return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642902094Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642906394Z     return await callback(context)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642910394Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/activity_handler.py", line 70, in on_turn
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642914594Z     await self.on_message_activity(turn_context)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642918694Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 61, in on_message_activity
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642922994Z     await self._send_card(turn_context, False)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642926894Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 121, in _send_card
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642931094Z     await self._send_welcome_card(turn_context, buttons)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642935194Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 135, in _send_welcome_card
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642939394Z     await turn_context.send_activity(
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642943294Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 174, in send_activity
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642947694Z     result = await self.send_activities([activity_or_text])
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642951694Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 226, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642955994Z     return await self._emit(self._on_send_activities, output, logic())
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642960594Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 304, in _emit
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642964994Z     return await logic
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642968895Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 221, in logic
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642973195Z     responses = await self.adapter.send_activities(self, output)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642977295Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 733, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642981695Z     raise error
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642988595Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 718, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642993095Z     response = await client.conversations.reply_to_activity(
2022-06-25T14:37:54.642997195Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/aio/operations_async/_conversations_operations_async.py", line 524, in reply_to_activity
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643001595Z     response = await self._client.async_send(
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643005595Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/async_client.py", line 115, in async_send
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643009795Z     pipeline_response = await self.config.pipeline.run(request, **kwargs)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643013895Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_abc.py", line 159, in run
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643018095Z     return await first_node.send(pipeline_request, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643022195Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_abc.py", line 79, in send
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643026395Z     response = await self.next.send(request, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643030395Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_requests.py", line 99, in send
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643034695Z     self._creds.signed_session(session)
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643038595Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/auth/app_credentials.py", line 98, in signed_session
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643042896Z     auth_token = self.get_access_token()
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643046896Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/auth/microsoft_app_credentials.py", line 65, in get_access_token
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643051296Z     return auth_token["access_token"]
2022-06-25T14:37:54.643055496Z KeyError: 'access_token'



2022-06-25T14:38:12.502028598Z
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502066398Z  [on_turn_error] unhandled error: 'access_token'
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502072298Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502076798Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 128, in run_pipeline
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502081298Z     return await self._middleware.receive_activity_with_status(
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502085398Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502089799Z     return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502093899Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502098099Z     return await callback(context)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502101999Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/activity_handler.py", line 70, in on_turn
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502118599Z     await self.on_message_activity(turn_context)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502122799Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 61, in on_message_activity
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502126899Z     await self._send_card(turn_context, False)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502130699Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 121, in _send_card
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502134799Z     await self._send_welcome_card(turn_context, buttons)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502138799Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 135, in _send_welcome_card
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502142799Z     await turn_context.send_activity(
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502146699Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 174, in send_activity
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502150799Z     result = await self.send_activities([activity_or_text])
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502154699Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 226, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502158899Z     return await self._emit(self._on_send_activities, output, logic())
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502162900Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 304, in _emit
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502167100Z     return await logic
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502170900Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 221, in logic
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502175000Z     responses = await self.adapter.send_activities(self, output)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502179700Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 733, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502184000Z     raise error
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502187900Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 718, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502192100Z     response = await client.conversations.reply_to_activity(
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502196000Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/aio/operations_async/_conversations_operations_async.py", line 524, in reply_to_activity
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502200700Z     response = await self._client.async_send(
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502204800Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/async_client.py", line 115, in async_send
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502208900Z     pipeline_response = await self.config.pipeline.run(request, **kwargs)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502213000Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_abc.py", line 159, in run
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502217100Z     return await first_node.send(pipeline_request, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502221000Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_abc.py", line 79, in send
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502229200Z     response = await self.next.send(request, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502233401Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_requests.py", line 99, in send
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502237601Z     self._creds.signed_session(session)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502241501Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/auth/app_credentials.py", line 98, in signed_session
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502245701Z     auth_token = self.get_access_token()
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502249601Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/auth/microsoft_app_credentials.py", line 65, in get_access_token
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502253801Z     return auth_token["access_token"]
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502257901Z KeyError: 'access_token'
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502261701Z
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502265401Z  [on_turn_error] unhandled error: 'access_token'
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502269401Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502273201Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 128, in run_pipeline
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502277301Z     return await self._middleware.receive_activity_with_status(
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502281201Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502285801Z     return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502289701Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502293901Z     return await callback(context)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502297701Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/activity_handler.py", line 70, in on_turn
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502301801Z     await self.on_message_activity(turn_context)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502305602Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 61, in on_message_activity
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502309702Z     await self._send_card(turn_context, False)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502313602Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 121, in _send_card
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502317602Z     await self._send_welcome_card(turn_context, buttons)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502321502Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/bots/teams_conversation_bot.py", line 135, in _send_welcome_card
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502325602Z     await turn_context.send_activity(
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502329402Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 174, in send_activity
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502333502Z     result = await self.send_activities([activity_or_text])
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502337402Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 226, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502345002Z     return await self._emit(self._on_send_activities, output, logic())
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502349302Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 304, in _emit
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502353402Z     return await logic
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502357102Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 221, in logic
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502361202Z     responses = await self.adapter.send_activities(self, output)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502365102Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 733, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502369302Z     raise error
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502373102Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 718, in send_activities
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502377203Z     response = await client.conversations.reply_to_activity(
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502381103Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/aio/operations_async/_conversations_operations_async.py", line 524, in reply_to_activity
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502385803Z     response = await self._client.async_send(
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502390003Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/async_client.py", line 115, in async_send
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502394203Z     pipeline_response = await self.config.pipeline.run(request, **kwargs)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502398103Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_abc.py", line 159, in run
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502402203Z     return await first_node.send(pipeline_request, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502406103Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_abc.py", line 79, in send
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502410203Z     response = await self.next.send(request, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502414003Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/msrest/pipeline/async_requests.py", line 99, in send
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502418103Z     self._creds.signed_session(session)
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502421903Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/auth/app_credentials.py", line 98, in signed_session
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502426103Z     auth_token = self.get_access_token()
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502429903Z   File "/tmp/8da56b4c179f50c/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botframework/connector/auth/microsoft_app_credentials.py", line 65, in get_access_token
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502434103Z     return auth_token["access_token"]
2022-06-25T14:38:12.502438103Z KeyError: 'access_token'
```

Comment: Sounds like it might be the credentials for your bot. Are you sure you have the App /Client Id and App / Client Secret configured correctly?

Comment: Yes, I‘m really sure

Comment: In your log stream you are getting aiohttp related error also. To resolve this please refer below thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160988/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-aiohttp

Comment: The instructions to fix the aiohttp error were already followed, but nonetheless the issue still exists. 
More interestingly sometimes the bot even works, but only for a limited amount of time and messaging him like 100 times.

Comment: Could you please share the bot Id and timestamp when the request is failing?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I'm not sure whether these informations could be crucial for the security

Comment: You can send the email on v-nivedipas@microsoft.com