# Error deploying echo-bot.py on Azure. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-webapps

I am following the Azure's [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-create-bot) on how to create and deploy a simple echo bot.

However, I have a problem when deploying. Here's the error:

```bash
2024-02-15T14:28:44.906911470Z    _____                               
2024-02-15T14:28:44.906996971Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2024-02-15T14:28:44.907002071Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2024-02-15T14:28:44.907005571Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2024-02-15T14:28:44.907008971Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2024-02-15T14:28:44.907012571Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2024-02-15T14:28:44.907015771Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2024-02-15T14:28:44.907019271Z 
2024-02-15T14:28:44.907022471Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2024-02-15T14:28:44.907025671Z Python 3.7.17
2024-02-15T14:28:44.907028771Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2024-02-15T14:28:47.919246257Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-02-15T14:28:48.126441484Z Site's appCommandLine: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --worker-class aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker --timeout 600 app:APP
2024-02-15T14:28:48.126477484Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -userStartupCommand 'gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0 --worker-class aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker --timeout 600 app:APP'
2024-02-15T14:28:48.187623605Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
2024-02-15T14:28:48.187668106Z Build Operation ID: 1014dbc4d99e9853
2024-02-15T14:28:48.197276572Z Output is compressed. Extracting it...
2024-02-15T14:28:48.205194026Z Extracting '/home/site/wwwroot/output.tar.gz' to directory '/tmp/8dc2e31979c41aa'...
2024-02-15T14:28:48.197713275Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20230707.1, Commit: 0bd28e69919b5e8beba451e8677e3345f0be8361, ReleaseTagName: 20230707.1
2024-02-15T14:28:50.351728409Z App path is set to '/tmp/8dc2e31979c41aa'
2024-02-15T14:28:51.165217213Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-02-15T14:28:51.425979509Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /tmp/8dc2e31979c41aa/antenv.
2024-02-15T14:28:51.449039868Z Updated PYTHONPATH to '/opt/startup/app_logs:/tmp/8dc2e31979c41aa/antenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages'
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296754676Z 
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296796276Z Error: class uri 'aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker' invalid or not found: 
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296803276Z 
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296807276Z [Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296811176Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.17/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 99, in load_class
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296815276Z     mod = importlib.import_module('.'.join(components))
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296819076Z   File "/opt/python/3.7.17/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296822976Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296826776Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296840176Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296844176Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296847976Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296851776Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296859076Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296862676Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296866477Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'
2024-02-15T14:28:55.296869977Z ]
```

I have found this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160988/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-aiohttp) but it did not solve my problem.

Here's my `requirements.txt`:

```bash
botbuilder_schema==4.13.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
aiohttp==3.6.3
botbuilder-integration-aiohttp==4.13.0
botbuilder-ai==4.13.0
botbuilder==0.0.1
botbuilder-core==4.13.0
botbuilder-dialogs==4.13.0
```

Here's my `.deployment`:

```bash
[config]
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true
```

Here are the files inside of my root folder:

- README.md
- **init**.py
- app.py
- bot.py
- config.py
- deploymentTemplates
- requirements.txt
- .deployment
- .env

And here's the command I am using to deploy the bot:
`az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group "resource_name" --name "service_name" --src "echo-bot.zip"`

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I was getting the same *no module named`aiohttp` found* error locally due to version incompatibility.

Follow below steps to deploy echo bot application.

I have created a python echo bot project with Python 3.9 version and able to run locally.

- Create and activate virtual environment

```py
py -m venv env
.\env\Scripts\activate
```

Added below packages in requirements.txt

```
botbuilder-integration-aiohttp>=4.14.0
aiohttp
botbuilder-core
botbuilder-schema
```

- Install required dependencies

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Local Response:**

[image]

- To deploy the application to Azure, add `init_func()` to **app.py** and modify the code as below:

```py
import sys
import traceback
from datetime import datetime
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.web import Request, Response, json_response
from botbuilder.core import (BotFrameworkAdapter, BotFrameworkAdapterSettings,
                             TurnContext)
from botbuilder.core.integration import aiohttp_error_middleware
from botbuilder.schema import Activity, ActivityTypes

from bot import MyBot
from config import DefaultConfig

CONFIG = DefaultConfig()

SETTINGS = BotFrameworkAdapterSettings(CONFIG.APP_ID, CONFIG.APP_PASSWORD)
ADAPTER = BotFrameworkAdapter(SETTINGS)

async def on_error(context: TurnContext, error: Exception):

    print(f"\n [on_turn_error] unhandled error: {error}", file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exc()

    await context.send_activity("The bot encountered an error or bug.")
    await context.send_activity(
        "To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code."
    )

    if context.activity.channel_id == "emulator":

        trace_activity = Activity(
            label="TurnError",
            name="on_turn_error Trace",
            timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
            type=ActivityTypes.trace,
            value=f"{error}",
            value_type="https://www.botframework.com/schemas/error",
        )
        await context.send_activity(trace_activity)

ADAPTER.on_turn_error = on_error

# Create the Bot
BOT = MyBot()

# Listen for incoming requests on /api/messages
async def messages(req: Request) -> Response:
    # Main bot message handler.
    if "application/json" in req.headers["Content-Type"]:
        body = await req.json()
    else:
        return Response(status=415)

    activity = Activity().deserialize(body)
    auth_header = req.headers["Authorization"] if "Authorization" in req.headers else ""

    response = await ADAPTER.process_activity(activity, auth_header, BOT.on_turn)
    if response:
        return json_response(data=response.body, status=response.status)
    return Response(status=201)
    
# enclosing the below code with init_func()

def init_func(argv):
    APP = web.Application(middlewares=[aiohttp_error_middleware])
    APP.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
    return APP
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP = init_func(None)

    try:
        web.run_app(APP, host="0.0.0.0", port=CONFIG.PORT)
    except Exception as error:
        raise error
```

- Create an **Azure Bot with Multi Tenant** and **Python Azure app service**.
- Open your Azure Bot and add the Web App's URL with `/api/messages i.e.,(https://<webappname>.azurewebsites.net)`in the `Azure Bot=>COnfiguration=>Message Endpoint`.
- Get the Microsoft App ID and create a secret to use its value as Microsoft App Password from the `Azure Bot=>Configuration`.
- Update the `Microsoft App ID and Microsoft App Password`  values in `Config.py`:

```py
class DefaultConfig:
    """ Bot Configuration """
    PORT = 3978
    APP_ID = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppId", "a573434f-3b7b-4e52-919a-c574d56965b5")
    APP_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("MicrosoftAppPassword", "mWk8Q~.6uGbHAvNzBlg3T6kikKfPUCaC7HV~sdpW")
```

- Deploy the Application to Azure.

[image]

- After deploying the application, add the Startup command in the`Azure App Service=>Configuration=>General settings`:

```py
python3 -m aiohttp.web -H 0.0.0.0 -P 8000 app:init_func
```

[image]

**Test the Bot:**

- Go to your `Azure Bot=>Settings=>Test in Web Chat` and test the chat bot as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! However I am still getting one error: 
`2024-02-16T08:32:29.267514758Z /tmp/8dc2ec96872817f/antenv/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'aiohttp.web' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp')`

It seems that it is not running `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3.11 (I saw that you were using the same from your screenshot). Are you uploading your venv folder? –

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded it.

Comment: I've uploaded it now. But I still get the error. See my logs here:  https://tmpfiles.org/dl/4224809/log.txt

How do I tell the container to use venv?

Comment: It works! My zip add an extra folder. It was root/contents and it should be just contents. Thank you very much!